# PHP - Redirect Loop Error

Tags: php

Everytime I go to my index.php page, I am getting the following error on Google Chrome:

> This webpage has a redirect loop

Oh my phpmyadmin database, if the text in account_type is 'deactivate', I made it so the user is automatically redirected to logout.php (This is in the functions.php page)

If it's 'active', then nothing happens.

My index.php code:

```
<?php include_once 'connect.php';?>
<?php include_once 'functions.php';?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="home-page">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>

      <ul class="linklist-admin">

        <?php
        if (loggedin()){ ?>
        <li><a href="profile">My Profile</a></li>

    <?php } else { ?>

            <li><a href="login.php">Sign In</a></li>

    <?php } ?>
      </ul>

    </body>
</html>
```

My functions.php code:

```
   <?php

session_start();

function loggedin(){
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && !empty($_SESSION['user_id'])){
    return true;
        } else {
            return false;
    }
    }

if(loggedin()){
$my_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$user_query = mysql_query("SELECT username, account_type FROM users WHERE id='$my_id'");
$run_user = mysql_fetch_array($user_query);
$username = $run_user['username'];
$account_type = $run_user['account_type'];

$query_level = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM user_level WHERE id='$user_level'");
$run_level = mysql_fetch_array($query_level);
$level_name = $run_level['name'];

$d = 'deactivate';
$a = 'active';

}



if($account_type == $d) { //logs you out if your account is deactivated.
header('location: logout.php');
}


?>
```

My logout.php code:

```
 <?php

include 'connect.php';
include 'functions.php';

session_destroy();

header('location: index.php');
```

Comment: If `functions.php` redirects to `logout.php`, and `logout.php` includes `functions.php`, then `logout.php` redirects endlessly to itself.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. How do I exactly fix it? Thanks.

Comment: A quick fix would be to move the `if($account_type == $d) { ... }` code inside of `if (logged_in()) { ... }`. That way, the redirection won't happen once the session is destroyed and the user is logged out. But the best idea is probably to reconsider your structure/logic because this type of thing can quickly become a spider web of redirects that grows increasingly difficult to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($account_type == $d) {

 //do stuff here 

}
```

I think that's what you want.